# Passing Publication List ID in custom Unsubscribe URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, landing-page, publicationlist, unsubscriber

I'm building a custom Unsub page for a client. In each email there should be a custom URL that passes the Publication list ID of the Publication list used for the send, so that users can unsubscribe from that publication list.

I know this functionality comes standard with the default Unsub Center but the client wants to ensure the visual aspect of their Unsub Center matches with their branding. And since default Unsub and Profile centers cannot be edited via HTML/CSS/etc they wanted to have a totally customized Unsub Page.

Fast forward to now, I am able to unsub/re-sub using a code I created with no problem, but the "lid" (list ID) value is fixed to the one I input.

But that "lid" value should be dynamically populated from the custom URL in the email.

How can I pass the List ID via the custom URL? I believe I would have to:

1. Retrieve the list ID
2. Declare the list ID as variable
3. Insert the variable in the URL

Is that correct? Any ideas on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The list ID is available as personalization string `%%listid%%`. You can just append this as parameter to your unsubscribe-link.

More information on personalization strings can be found in the [Marketing Cloud documentation about personalization string](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/)

Answer (score 2):

I your custom unsubscribe page is part of a Microsite, then you can link to it with the  [**MicrositeURL()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/MicrositeURL.htm) function, which includes the send context automatically.  There'd be no need to pass it in plain text in the URL.

In the landing page you'd just do an `Attribute.GetValue("listid")` in SSJS or a `AttributeValue("listid")` in AMPScript.

Comment: Thanks Adam and Markus, both answers have been very helpful! However I have not been able to get the MicrositeURL() function to work.

Here's what I have so far:

URL in the email> `<a alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false" href="%%=MicrositeURL(586, publicationlistid, listid)=%%" title="MyPage">Click to unsubscribe</a>`

But when I open the link in the email once it's being sent I get a page with the message: "The page you have requested is unavailable!"

The landing page within the microsite has been published and I can access it via its own URL.

Not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: I have tried several different forms of linking to the landing page within the microsite I created, and I have been getting errors all over. For instance I tried using both `<a href="%%=MicrositeURL(77777)=%%">Landing Page URL</a>` and `<a href="%%=v(MicrositeURL(77777)=%%">Link</a>` and also `<p><a href="%%=RedirectTo(MicrositeURL(77777))=%%">Click to unsubscribe</a></p>` to no avail. The email is sent correctly, but on all situations I get a page saying "The page you have requested is unavailable!" upon clicking the link. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I should contact Support..

Comment: Do you have the correct PageID?

Comment: Here's one I pulled from a working configuration: `<a href='%%=MicrositeURL(8722337,"subscriberMID", "9999999")=%%'>Page</a>`

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'm positive I have right Page ID. It should be this:

`Page Details
Status
Published
Created
02/28/2017 11:01 AM
Last Updated
03/01/2017 09:27 AM
URL
http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/XXXXXX
Page ID
586`

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. I inserted %%_EmailID%% in the landing page to print the page ID to ensure I got the right one, but when the landing page opens in a new browser tab it only shows "0".

Is %%_EmailID%% a correct way for printing the page ID or is there a different method? I usually just go to the Microsite Properties and then the page properties and I see "Page ID XXX" (only 3 digits).